# Raku portable edition

Tags: raku

Is there a portable edition of raku?

Or its possible to compile it and install some modules zip all to one directory, and then unzip on different machines having the same OS?

Comment: Which OS?  It might make a difference.  Nowadays, I'd take a look at docker for this type of thing.

Comment: Windows ,also if there are an option to do this on Linux it would be great

Comment: Is there...? Please use an internet search engine, this is off-topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5):

If both computers have the same filesystem layout -- maybe. At the very least all absolute paths to these items would need to be identical or else you'd have bad precompiled files everywhere.

Of course this is not a very practical solution ( how many computers do you have with the same *home* directory ), but for instance you could ( and indeed we used to ): build rakudo inside of travis-ci, push the entire folder to a private repo, and then could pull that repo down from other travis instances to get an already-built version of the very latest rakudo release.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can run Perl 6 on Android: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1324, but current there is no package for Perl 6 on Termux.

Comment: Are you the same user as https://stackoverflow.com/users/5829526/chenyf? If so, you might want to flag your own question here and ask to have your accounts combined.

Comment: @Christopher Bottoms Yes, the same user, I'd glad that if somebody can combine my accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Some time in 2019 Rakudo gained the ability to be relocated. Since the 2019.11 release pre-compiled, relocatable binaries are provided for every release. They can be downloaded from [rakudo.org](https://rakudo.org/downloads).

So you can download such an archive, extract it to some folder, install modules with the included package manager `zef`, bundle it up with your own code, zip it and it will work on any computer (given it's the same architecture and OS), in any folder.